# Is there any method make property animator API work in the android system which below 3.0

Tags: android, animation

[property animator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) API introduced in Android 3.0,it can't work in Android 2.0.Is there any  method make property animator API work in the android system which below 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

[NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) is a library created by the legendary Jake Wharton that brings the Android 3.0 Animation APIs all the way back to Android 1.0 . It has 1-to-1 API comparability, which means all the examples you see on the web will work and you don't have to update too much when everyone inevitably drops support for pre-3.0 devices.

Comment: This does work well but there are some issues. I used this library and found that your view position does not update after the animation occurred on versions prior to android 3.0. So click events cannot be handled on the new position of the view. I tried using invalidate but this did not solve the issue. Just a note.

Comment: @Neil, yeah, I believe that's a known bug with the library, unfortunately.